# ck patch for Linux 3.13

Tags: linux-kernel, patch

Does anyone have any news about the -ck patches for Linux 3.13 kernel tree?
I've checked [here](http://ck.kolivas.org/patches/3.0/) but there's nothing yet...

Comment: You'd have to ask the owner...

Answer (score 3):

That's where you're supposed to look. If they're not there, then Con hasn't gotten around to porting them yet. Compare the file dates on the patches for the older kernels to the corresponding kernel release date, and you'll see that it usually takes him anywhere from two to six weeks. He's doing this in his spare time...

Answer (score 1):

New answer to ensure you're seeing it: The 3.13 ck patches are up at http://ck.kolivas.org/patches/3.0/3.13/3.13-ck1/ and they apply cleanly to 3.13.5.